# Mixed Audience Sign In clarification

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-games

I am a Games Developer currently making a game in Unity that I will release on Android and iOS. My game is intended to be 'mixed audience' - that is, that it is targeted both at children under 13, and everyone else. Hopefully then my game will also qualify for the 'Designed for Family' category.

The Google Play Games Services Checklist [Google Play Games Services Checklist](https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist)
states:

> Important: If you have a mixed audience game (defined as a game with children under 13 as one of the intended audiences), even if children are not the primary audience, you must include a sign-in button as described in 1.1.2 below. Automatic sign-in is prohibited for mixed audience games.

However it also says:

> Allow players to stay signed-in. After the player signs in
>   successfully to your game, connect them automatically whenever your
>   game starts, until the player explicitly signs out.

I just need some clarification:

If I have a button to sign in on the main menu of my game, and the user signs in (i.e. they are over 13), then when I next launch the game, should I automatically log them into GPGS on the launch screen? Or does it mean that I have to get my players to click the GPGS login button every time they launch the game?

What is the correct way to implement sign in (and automatic sign in?) to meet the mixed audience requirements?

I apologise for posting here but the [Google Support Page](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/support) says to post here, there is no link to email any sort of Google Developer Support.

Comment: It says to post technical questions, this really isn't a technical question, it is a question in regards to COPPA compliance: 

https://play.google.com/about/families/coppa-compliance/

Comment: Also: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994?hl=en